# PHP - session_set_cookie_params and session_get_cookie_params

Tags: php

im looking into sessions a bit more and would like some input.

on a simple login form once the form is submited i have the following

```
.
..
...
session_name('TOKEN');
session_set_cookie_params( time() + 600, './', 'example.co.uk', false, false);
session_start();
$_SESSION['TOKEN'] = TOKEN;
...
..
.
```

and then when a request to the server is made I have this.

```
.
..
...
session_name('TOKEN');
$session_data = session_get_cookie_params();
print_r($session_data);
...
..
.
```

which returns `Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => [httponly] => )`

as you can see something is not working or I am missing something or im going a little potty!

anyway, If anyone has any input on where im going wrong i would love to here it!

Answer (score 5):

You may have figured it out already, but session_set_cookie_params() needs to be called before session_start() for every single page request.  So sayth the manual entry for the function.

Comment: +1 for the 'correct' answer, this is def what's happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is not to touch session cookie params at all
sessions works pretty fine with default values. and with manual correction you'd make it worst.

as for your question, session_get_cookie_params works fine. it shows you current settings which don't seem to be altered in this another file.

Comment: I don't see how that answers this question other than offering an opinion.  Most implementations of 'remember me' use the expires field of the session cookie for their implementation AFAIK, Zend Framework would be 1 case in point.

Comment: "expires field of the session cookie" is an oxymoron.

Comment: While I understand your point, it's still not a valid answer to the question.  I do enjoy the roundabout rip on Zend Framework though, yet another failure in an overall shabby framework.  See for yourself in the `Zend_Session::rememberUntil()`  [implementation](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Session.php)

Comment: I would agree except for cross sub-domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

i think it may work

```
session_set_cookie_params( time() + 600, '/', '.example.co.uk', false, false);
```

> '/' not './'
>
> '.example.co.uk' not 'example.co.uk'

this worked fine for me.